# nginx. limit_req срабатывает из-за prefligt-запроса

Tags: nginx

Занимаюсь настройкой доступа к API от веб-приложения. Приложение находится на другом домене, поэтому мне не избавиться от preflight запроса методом OPTIONS. Однако, он идет сразу перед первым запросом POST, поэтому срабатывает ограничение (т.к. preflight-запрос и запрос с полезной нагрузкой идут сразу же). Можно ли в limit_req игнорировать запрос методом OPTIONS или как-то по другому решить эту проблему?

Comment: А зачем вам такой зверский limit_req?

Comment: Почему зверский? Я просто хочу поставить ограничение по кол-ву запросов на раздел /api/ на всякий случай, может быть ситуация, что кто-то захочет получить данные в обход приложения, чтобы не было лишних нагрузок

Comment: Проблема-то здесь в том, что nginx делает ограничение в пересчете на секунду, поэтому даже если я ставлю приемлемое и даже большое количество запросов в минуту, в пересчете на секунду получается слишком мало. Ну, например, 300 запросов в минуту - это 5 запросов в секунду, т.е. по запросу каждые 0,2 секунды, не чаще. Мой POST отправляется сразу после OPTIONS, поэтому это ограничение превышается

Comment: Используйте burst и nodelay

Comment: Ну или можно ключ составить так что бы OPTIONS в него не попадали, но мне кажется что burst проще

Comment: Посмотрел-подумал, решил остаться все-таки на burst на один пакет, вы правы, это оптимальное решение будет